# How to set 3d image through css3

Tags: html, css

I have a design with some 3d graphical images but i am not set images with css3 or other method. I have attach a sample image please give me right solution with css code.

Thanking you

[image]

Comment: Its unclear what your problem is and what you are asking for. Please elaborate and provide codes of what you have tried and which part of the code isn't working.

Comment: How to set shape above type of image via css, means which method i use for these images like rotate or skew. I try it but i am not set in right shape

Comment: leave it! it will be messy and you'll face browser support issues as well..! Simply take your images in photoshop, create a transparent layer behind it, and then Skew and change perspective of your images using Photoshop Transform tools! and save it as PNG and use on your website

Comment: Mr. Deepak i think you are not understand my problem, these images change by client through admin panel so i used only css technique with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
.container {
  perspective: 400px;
  perspective-origin: center center;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

img:hover {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.rightimg {
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-20deg);
}

.leftimg {
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cxj1je4b/)